# Am I correct that Robolectric doesn't support Spinner right now

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

Tried to test Dialog with Spinner and got:

```
NullPointerException: can't get shadow for null
```

Am I correct that Robolectric doesn't support Spinner right now?

As well it's not possible to register shadow for it?

Comment: Are you doing things will null that don't make sense?

Comment: I'm doing `setContentView()` and after `findViewById()` for `Spinner` and get NPE at this line

Comment: My fault - I mocked the owner activity. That's why Dialog wasn't able to inflate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault - I mocked the owner activity. That's why Dialog wasn't able to inflate